# how to use join with object type

Tags: java

I am trying to learn basic concepts before jumping on to bigger one. 
below is my toString method, which invokes a method(converter) which returns string . I have several classes all having toString but different number of objects for each converter, the way i am doing it is working but i want work it in a more basic fashion as this seems to be a bit advance for my current work. All comments will be appreciated. thanks!!

```
        public String toString() 
          {
            return converter(obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4);
          }
```

Converter method is :

```
        protected String converter(Object... values)
         {
          return StringUtils.join(values, ",");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public String toString() 
 {
      return obj1 + ", " + obj2 + ", " + obj3 + ", " + obj4;
 }
```

Is this what you want? You have to remember that these `obj` toString()s may not result the way you want

You may have to override the `obj` `toString()` also to get your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something more "basic" you could just write for example

return obj1 + "," + obj2 + "," + obj3 + "," + obj4

But honestly I don't see anything wrong with your current approach, assuming that just joining a bunch of values separated by commas fits the bill for all your toString methods.